# Get related and unrelated rows at the same queryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities that until recently had no related but now, for statistical reasons I had to relate.

The fact is that now I have X number of unrelated records that my client has asked me to show in statistics as "unknown origin".

I must create a list of "products" with its origin and making products that are not related, show as origin "unknown origin".

This can be done through a QueryBuilder?

I paste a sample of my queryBuilder.

```
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('p')
                ->where('p.provider = :provider')
                ->join('p.inventory', 'i')
                ->setParameter('provider', $provider);
```

It returns me just related results.

Some tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `leftJoin` instead of join, then group the results manually, and remove the `where` calll if you want all products.